# Transformers pretrained model with dropout setting

Tags: python, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to use transformer's huggingface pretrained model `bert-base-uncased`, but I want to increace dropout. There isn't any mention to this in `from_pretrained` method, but colab ran the object instantiation below without any problem. I saw these dropout parameters in `classtransformers.BertConfig` documentation.

Am I using bert-base-uncased AND changing dropout in the correct way?

```
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
        pretrained_model_name_or_path='bert-base-uncased',
        num_labels=2,
        output_attentions = False,
        output_hidden_states = False,
        attention_probs_dropout_prob=0.5,
        hidden_dropout_prob=0.5
    )
```

Answer (score 8):

As [Elidor00](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64959535/7924573) already said it, your assumption is correct. Similarly I would suggest using a separated Config because it is easier to export and less prone to cause errors. Additionally someone in the comments ask how to use it via `from_pretrained`:

```py
from transformers import BertModel, AutoConfig

configuration = AutoConfig.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
configuration.hidden_dropout_prob = 0.5
configuration.attention_probs_dropout_prob = 0.5
        
bert_model = BertModel.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path = 'bert-base-uncased', 
config = configuration)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is correct, but note that there are two dropout parameters and that you are using a specific Bert model, that is `BertForSequenceClassification`.

Also as suggested by the documentation you could first define the configuration and then the way in the following way:

```
from transformers import BertModel, BertConfig

# Initializing a BERT bert-base-uncased style configuration
configuration = BertConfig()

# Initializing a model from the bert-base-uncased style configuration
model = BertModel(configuration)

# Accessing the model configuration
configuration = model.config
```

Comment: how does it work with the `from_pretrained()` function?

Comment: I recommend you to see [this example](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/legacy/token-classification/run_ner.py) to understand how it works. A simple example of token classification made with bert

Comment: maybe you can change your answer to include a working example that answers OP question with your suggested config solution (Personally I tried passing a config to the `from_pretrained` function and had some problems, but maybe I was doing it wrong)

Comment: The answer on how to use ```from_pretrained()``` for config, model and tokenizer can be found in the link I sent, exactly [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/legacy/token-classification/run_ner.py#L167). In case you are not clear about something, I advise you to ask a new question: explain your problem well and insert the code you are using, otherwise it is very difficult to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

What you did is just fine, but for the classifiers layer we have another parameter that is needed to set called `classifier_dropout`. In case you don't specify that, it will use the `hidden_dropout_prob` as fallback value.